# Android Hamburger Menu Interaction

Tags: android

I am working on an android app where there is a drawer layout in the actionbar. I have added listeners for the drawerlayout to listen for when the drawer is opened or closed. There is a navigation view attached to the drawerlayout.

Now the drawer can be opened and closed in various ways : tap-to-open, swipe-to-open, swipe-to-close and tap-outside-to-close. I have to add events to identify each of these separately.

I have added the drawerlayout and navigationview in this way :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    />
```

Noe in the Activity, I have added the following listeners on navigationview and drawerlayout.

```
//Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

                 // Switch case identify different options

            }
        }
    });

    // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Now `onDrawerOpened` and `onDrawerClosed` gives me information only about when drawer is opened and closed. How do I distinguish between interactions to open and close ?  Interactions to identify :  `tap-to-open, swipe-to-open, swipe-to-close and tap-outside-to-close`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ActionBarDrawerToggle` offers more than just the `onDrawerClosed`, `onDrawerOpened` methods. You override the `onDrawerSlide` method to detect slides:

```
.. 
@Override
public void onDrawerSlide (View drawerView,float slideOffset){

   if(determine if openning or closing){
     doStuff();
   }else{
     doOtherStuff();
   }
}
```

Taps on the toolbar can be deteced by overriding the `Activity.onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method. Then check if the item has the id `android.R.id.home`.

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to accurate determine if drawer was opened by sliding, using some existing parameters and writing a different method:

```
        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

            if (newState == DrawerLayout.STATE_DRAGGING) {

                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    // drawer is currently open and is being closed by sliding
                } else {
                    // drawer is currently closed and is being opened by sliding
                }
            }
        }
```

I will add for detecting the tap events correctly, once I get to know. If somebody know, please comment.